# Prevent external user route from browser tab

Tags: angular

There is an input field in the application. After the external user writes a string in this field, I send it to the web api and retrieve the object matching that string from the database. And I route to that object.

for instance; `localhost/products/4`

However, when I type this `localhost/products/4` into the browser address bar, I do not want it to be accessed. I just want you to be able to route there as a result of entering a password in the field.

I solved the access barriers for the user with canActivate. But how do I do it for external user?

Comment: So you want only authenticated users can access `localhost/products/4` , right ?

Comment: There is a field. For example, external users (site visitors, not users) can access localhost:/xxx/products/id:5 by typing a password in this field. I want them to be NOT able to access it by typing this url in the address bar and only typing the password in the field.

Comment: In the canactivate have some conditions to check if the user has is authenticated or external